# How can I add a Google+ person to Gtalk?

Tags: gmail, google-plus, google-talk

How can I add a Google+ person (someone in my circles) to GTalk?  There seems like there should be an easy way since GTalk (chat) is now embedded in Google+.

[image: Google Plus Screen Cap]

Searching my friend's names doesn't work, and I can't always see an e-mail address on a G+ profile.

Answer (score 1):

When they first rolled out Google+, they automatically added everyone on your circles to your chat list, if the other party had also enabled this chat setting. But this became a privacy issue and it was soon dropped.
Now the only way is to get their email address and add them manually to your chat list.

Comment: I guess now the setting is back on Google+ where you can have people on your circles back. But I guess, if you need to have them forever, you just need to ask them for their email ids.

Comment: Not at all correct for current state.